# Can't set focus

Tags: jquery, wordpress, focus

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#mega-menu-item-11195').on('open_panel', function() { 
       $('#woocommerce-product-search-field-0').focus();
    });
});
```

I'm trying to get the focus to set in the search field when the search icon is clicked on the mobile version of the menu at http://www.pyxelstudio.com using the above code, I can't see why it's not working.

If I change .focus to .hide it works a like charm, so selectors all appear to be correct!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code that triggers the event?  Do you have an element with id `mega-menu-item-11195`?  If so, it should work.  Something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#openButton').click(function() {
    $('#mega-menu-item-11195').trigger('open_panel');
  });

  $('#mega-menu-item-11195').on('open_panel', function() { 
     $('#woocommerce-product-search-field-0').focus();
  });
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sq52bnrh/1/) that I believe demonstrates the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: `mega-menu-item-11195` is a list item in the menu. I'm not sure where the code that triggers it, part of the Max Mega Menu Plugin!

Comment: The panel is opening perfectly fine, if i change `$('#woocommerce-product-search-field-0').focus();` to `$('#woocommerce-product-search-field-0').hide();` the latter works fine so it's something to do with the focus (i'm not using the dev console)